# xml parser delegates not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, rss, nsxmlparser

Iam new to ios development, i need to parse xml data into an array, i tried a tutorial, and i am not getting data, when edited with "**hrms.atrity.info/api/people**"
XML url ,Parser delegates not working while executing with the above link.Here is my coding, it works with "**image.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss**".How to rectify this probe,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://hrms.atrity.info/api/people"];//NOt Working
    NSURL *url = [NSURL
                  URLWithString:@"http://image.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss"];//This Works
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [xmlParser parse];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
(NSInteger)section
{
    return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"FirstName"];
    return cell;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:
(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    element = elementName;
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"Users"])
    {
        item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:
(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Users"])
    {
        [item setObject:title forKey:@"FirstName"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"LastName"];
        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];
        NSLog(@"%@",feeds);
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"FirstName"])
    {
        [title appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([element isEqualToString:@"LastName"])
    {
        [link appendString:string];
    }
}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the issue ? Please add more details, are you getting parsed data ?

Comment: i got the data in console, but parser delegates are not working.I added  parser delegate also.

Comment: @Vijay: Please put break point in all delegates. Then check problem in delegate or not?

Comment: Problem is when you request this from browser, you may see XML, but when you request from `initWithContentsOfURL`, you'll get JSON. Like neilco says, specify request that says that you want to accept XML only, and you'll get XML. (Or you could take the JSON and parse that with `NSJSONSerialization`.) Also, with `NSXMLParserDelegate`, always implement `parseErrorOccurred`, because otherwise you're flying blind.

Comment: @Rob: I already check the URL it gives XML data only

Comment: @TamilKing Did you check in a web browser? That's not a good way to check, because you actually _will_ get XML that way. But if you do `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]` and look at the response there, you'll get JSON! That's why you have to use neilco's technique of specifying a request that accepts XML.

Comment: @Rob:Yes you correct. It gives JSON Value only.

Comment: @Vijay:The Working URL(http://image.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss) has property rss so only it gives XML data, it works fine. The not working url(http://hrms.atrity.info/api/people) gives JSON value that is the problem. Thanks Rob

Answer (score 2):

Using the following code:

```
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://hrms.atrity.info/api/people"]];
```

is resulting in the `parser:parseErrorOccurred:` being called for the `http://hrms.atrity.info/api/people` URL. The `NSError` passed to that delegate shows an error code of `4` which translate to `NSXMLParserEmptyDocumentError`. This is because the URL is returning JSON instead of XML. You can check this using the following code:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://hrms.atrity.info/api/people"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

You can clearly see in the console in Xcode that the data is JSON. In order to retrieve the data in XML format, you need to specify the `Accept` header with a value of `application/xml`. You cannot do this with `NSURL` alone and will need to use `NSMutableURLRequest` so that you can set the custom header value, as follows:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://hrms.atrity.info/api/people"]];
[request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Comment: Quite right. I'd only suggest using `sendAsynchronousRequest` (because you should never do `sendSynchronousRequest` from the main queue). Regardless, my apologies for down-voting your original answer (I looked at response in browser and saw XML, and dismissed your answer too quickly). But +1 now!

Comment: @Rob No worries. I used `sendSynchronous` request because, for the purposes of the answer, it's the quickest way of getting to the `NSData`.